# NEMA 23 RPM with a tb6600 driver

Tags: stepper-motor, stepper-driver

I want to run a [NEMA 23](https://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/203330522892?_trkparms=amclksrc%3DITM%26aid%3D777008%26algo%3DPERSONAL.TOPIC%26ao%3D1%26asc%3D20220705100511%26meid%3D96b588cc8f2c4c209bdf2efcda20c221%26pid%3D101524%26rk%3D1%26rkt%3D1%26itm%3D203330522892%26pmt%3D1%26noa%3D1%26pg%3D2380057%26algv%3DRecentlyViewedItemsV2%26brand%3DStepperOnline&_trksid=p2380057.c101524.m146925&_trkparms=pageci%3Ab00a3e04-e906-11ed-b7bb-66058dc979c6%7Cparentrq%3Add4d52e61870a12b7c915c7affffd2a4%7Ciid%3A1) with a [tb6600](https://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/304886290711?_trkparms=amclksrc%3DITM%26aid%3D777008%26algo%3DPERSONAL.TOPIC%26ao%3D1%26asc%3D20220705100511%26meid%3D96b588cc8f2c4c209bdf2efcda20c221%26pid%3D101524%26rk%3D1%26rkt%3D1%26itm%3D304886290711%26pmt%3D1%26noa%3D1%26pg%3D2380057%26algv%3DRecentlyViewedItemsV2%26brand%3DUnbranded&_trksid=p2380057.c101524.m146925&_trkparms=pageci%3Ab00a3e04-e906-11ed-b7bb-66058dc979c6%7Cparentrq%3Add4d52e61870a12b7c915c7affffd2a4%7Ciid%3A1) driver. The motor needs 2.8 amps, 24 volts. The tb6600 can output 4 amps. The voltage output of the tb6600 isn't specified on the link above but I google it and apparently the tb6600 can only output 5 volts. Let me know if that's true. If it is, what's the maximum rpm and torque I could get from the motor with the driver. The picture below can be found from the NEMA 23 link. As you can see it shows that the motor can reach 1350 RPM at 24V or 36V. Can these speeds be achieved with a tb6600?

[image]
I've seen someone use a tb6600 driver to achieve ~1800 RPM. Here's the [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oQGNgRZiO84&ab_channel=GBWM), skip to 1.30 for demo. I don't want to use a DM54T driver because it's too expensive and overkill for what I'm doing.

Answer (score 1):

5 V is just for the logic side of the driver.  According to [THIS](https://www.dfrobot.com/product-1547.html) it can take 9 - 42 VDC to drive motors.  The voltage output will be whatever it needs to be (up to near the supply voltage) to satisfy the current requirement you have set it for.

Yes, you should be able to achieve the 1350 RPM with this setup.  1800 may also be possible, but there will be very little torque at those speeds.

[Wiki page for your TB6600 Driver](https://wiki.dfrobot.com/TB6600_Stepper_Motor_Driver_SKU__DRI0043)

Comment: I've got the driver and the motor now but I haven't managed to get it to 1350 RPM. When I decrease the delay between each step the motor stalls and at it's max speed it is nowhere near 1000 RPM. The power supply is at 14 volts 2.8 amps. Do I just need to increase the voltage?

Comment: @RaminMoradi Increased voltage may do it, since you are at the lower end of the range.  You could also try reducing the amount of microstepping, if that doesn't work.